# How `G` type of python % string formatting behave?

Tags: python

I [read](https://realpython.com/python-input-output/#the-string-modulo-operator):

> The `g` and `G` conversion types choose between floating point or exponential output, depending on the magnitude of the exponent and the value specified for `.<precision>`. Output is the same as `e`/`E` if the exponent is less than -4 or not less than `.<precision>`. Otherwise, it’s the same as `f`/`F`:

Also, I didnt get "if the exponent is less than -4 or not less than `.<precision>`". Where do we specify exponent explicitly? By "exponent", does it mean number of digits after decimal point? I feel so, as when I tried to have four digits after decimal points, it printed it as `f`, but when I tried having five digits after decimal points, it printed it as `e`:

```
>>> '%g' % 0.0003
'0.0003'
>>> '%g' % 0.00003
'3e-05'
```

**Q1.** Am I correct with above understanding?

**Q2.** But, then, I didnt get why it did not do same in below example:

```
>>> '%g' % 3.14
'3.14'
>>> '%g' % 3.014
'3.014'
>>> '%g' % 3.0014
'3.0014'
>>> '%g' % 3.00014
'3.00014'
>>> '%g' % 3.000014
'3.00001'
>>> '%g' % 3.0000014
'3'
```

**Q3.** Finally, I didnt get "or not less than `.<precision>`" part of "if the exponent is less than -4 or not less than `.<precision>`". I tried to explicitly specify precision less than and more than 4 digits after decimal point. But it still printed the same:

```
>>> '%g' % 0.00003
'3e-05'
>>> '%.3g' % 0.00003
'3e-05'
>>> '%.9g' % 0.00003
'3e-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

*By "exponent", does it mean number of digits after decimal point?*

No. Exponent is simply speaking number you get after `e` in notation, for example `0.999` might be rendered as `9.990000e-01` which mean exponent of `0.999` is `-1`. Exponent value does inform about *order of magnitude*.

Answer (score 0):

As per C11 standard:

> A **double** argument representing a floating-point number is
> converted in style `f` or `e` (or in style `F` or `E` in the case of a `G`
> conversion specifier), depending on the value converted and the
> precision. Let *P* equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is
> omitted, or 1 if the precision is zero. Then, if a conversion with
> style `E` would have an exponent of *X*:
>
> if *P* > *X* ≥ −4, the conversion is
> with style `f` (or `F`) and precision *P − (X + 1)*.
>      otherwise, the
> conversion is with style `e` (or `E`) and precision *P* − 1.
>
> A **double** argument
> representing an infinity or NaN is converted in the style of an `f` or `F`
> conversion specifier.

Also from [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html) another description of the same behaviour is:

> General format.  For a given precision `p >= 1`,
> this rounds the number to `p` significant digits and
> then formats the result in either fixed-point format
> or in scientific notation, depending on its magnitude.
>
> The precise rules are as follows: suppose that the
> result formatted with presentation type `'e'` and
> precision `p-1` would have exponent `exp`.  Then
> if `-4 <= exp < p`, the number is formatted
> with presentation type `'f'` and precision
> `p-1-exp`.  Otherwise, the number is formatted
> with presentation type `'e'` and precision `p-1`.
> In both cases insignificant trailing zeros are removed
> from the significand, and the decimal point is also
> removed if there are no remaining digits following it.
>
> Positive and negative infinity, positive and negative
> zero, and nans, are formatted as `inf`, `-inf`,
> `0`, `-0` and `nan` respectively, regardless of
> the precision.
>
> A precision of `0` is treated as equivalent to a
> precision of `1`.  The default precision is `6`.